# How do I get Perl's HTTP::Daemon to accept more than one connection?

Tags: perl, http, daemon

I do some testing with HTTP::Daemon:

```
use HTTP::Daemon;
use HTTP::Status;

my $d = HTTP::Daemon->new || die;
print "Please contact me at: <URL:", $d->url, ">\n";
while (my $c = $d->accept) {
  while (my $r = $c->get_request) {
      if ($r->method eq 'GET') {
          # do some action (about 10s)
      }
      else {
          $c->send_error(RC_FORBIDDEN)
      }
    }
  $c->close;
  undef($c);
}
```

It works fine, but if I do more request within 10s, the requests gets queued (I get all requests through $d->accept)

What I want is the following:  if a client starts a request, no other should be queued.
I tried with the Listen option, but without success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

HTTP::Daemon doesn't fork for you, and explicitely tells you so [in its documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aDaemon).

> This HTTP daemon does not fork(2) for you.  Your application, i.e. the
>   user of the "HTTP::Daemon" is responsible for forking if that is
>   desirable.  Also note that the user is responsible for generating
>   responses that conform to the HTTP/1.1 protocol.

If your answering takes too long, fork to answer.  Or use another module.

Comment: I do not want to fork - thats ok. But during answer generation i do not want that subsequent requests get queued.

Comment: Well what do you want to happen to them then?

Comment: "Ignoring" in this context is still a bit vague. In a sense, your code is already ignoring concurrent connections: it's not doing anything specific about them until they come to the front of the queue.  Unless you're willing to delve deeper in tcp, doing something specific means having code for it, and to run that code while the previous query is processing, you need multitasking.  Hence forking.

Comment: you can use $c->force_last_request after you handled the request in the loop this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

you have one thread here; it can either handle the first request or handle the next one to come in. You can't deal with new requests until control goes back to accept.